# Complexity of number guessing game

Tags: probability

Consider the game of guessing some number k chosen from a set K where we don't know the distribution of this selection. An algorithm to do so would be:

```
Input: a set of possible keys K = {k1, . . . , kN}
Challenger interface: input is an element of K,
output is Boolean
1: pick a random permutation σ of {1, . . . , N}
2: for all i = 1 to N do
3:  if query k_σ(i) answers yes then
4:   yield k_σ(i) and stop
5:  end if
6: end for
```

It is claim that the expected number of iterations is

$E[\text{#iterations}] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E(P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}])i$

finally it says that $ E(P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}]) = \frac{1}{N}$

I don't see what is the mening of $E(P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}])$. Is $P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}]$ a random variable? Also why is it $ E(P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}]) = \frac{1}{N}$?

Comment: $K = K_{\sigma(i)}$ is an event for each $i$.  $P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}]$ is both a conditional probability and a random variable, with the property $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}] =1$.

Comment: @henry $P[K = K_{\sigma(i)}]$ is a random variable over the set 1 to N or over the set of permutations?

Comment: It does not matter much here, but I would say it is a random variable over the possible permutations. Apparently you do not know $P[K = K_i]$ so, if you are prepared to take a Bayesian approach, you could also say it is a random variable over the index.  What does matter is the expectation of the sum.